# pagesetup excel Worksheets and i didn't have access control to printer

Tags: c#, vba, excel, printing

I faced the problem with a blow code that i need to change the excel page setup(orientation zoom or any property but the default printer is not available, i didn't have permessions to access printer or found so this code raised exception.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileFullPath);
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;                    
var with1 = book.Worksheets[sheetName].PageSetup;
with1.zoom = false;
with1.FitToPagesWide = 1;
with1.FitToPagesTall = 1;
with1.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
```

the exception is:

```
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Unable to set the Zoom property of the PageSetup class
Target Site: Void CheckThrowException(Int32, System.Dynamic.ExcepInfo ByRef, UInt32, System.String)
Source: Microsoft Excel
Stack Trace: at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , Boolean )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Boolean )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at ExcelProcessing.ThumbGeneration.ExcelSheetSnapShoot(String fileFullPath, String thumbDir, String sheetName, String thumbResolution, String cropArea, String PDFFilesDir)
```

note:
the exception happened when no printers found as default to when change page layout properties throw this exception so i need to any other thing to export excel file as lanscape PDF

Comment: Where and what exception? (The `xlApp.Visible = false` is useless because after the creation is not visible)

Comment: i added the exception this error is happened when the current user cannot access to default printer (printer not found or didn't have permission)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it wouldn't fit in a comment, so I put it here.

I would like to check if the same steps work from another Excel session instead of C#.

Try to start Excel create this macro and run it. It will create a second Excel session just like your C# function does. I tried in my computer and it works.

If it works, then very likely it's a problem with .net.

If it doesn't, then very likely it's a problem with the file the hidden session is opening.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim Exl As New Application, Wb As Workbook, PS As PageSetup
  Set Wb = Exl.Workbooks.Open("Test.xls")
  Set PS = Wb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  PS.Zoom = False
  PS.FitToPagesWide = 1
  PS.FitToPagesTall = 1
  PS.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
  Exl.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: the exception happened when no printers found as default to when change page layout properties throw this exception so i need to any other thing to export excel file as lanscape PDF